# How to install Memcache in EasyApache4

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm

friends,

I am using easyapche4 on my WHM server. I am not able to find any guide about how to install Memcache or APC in easyapache4 on my whm server. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, easy steps https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/6066507